# rsync fails only when initiated via cron

Tags: shell-script, cron, rsync

I'm attempting to `rsync` files to my local machine from a remote server on boot via a `crontab` entry. My `rsync` script waits for `resolv.conf` to be configured by DHCP processes, then begins the `rsync`. Unfortunately when the script is run on boot, `rsync` fails with the following error:

```
2019/09/05 12:37:22 [392] rsync: getaddrinfo: [server-name.domain.tld] 873: Name or service not known
2019/09/05 12:37:22 [392] rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

I've tried a couple modifications to better understand the issue:

1. Since this client is *currently* on my local network, and my local network supports mDNS, I tried switching to `[server-name.local]`, and initiated the script. That works as expected.
2. Next, I tried manually running the `rsync` command once the client was fully booted. No change to the command from the script, and using `[server-name.domain.tld]`. That works.

```
rsync -avy  --log-file=$script_path/$logfile --password-file $script_path/$password_file --contimeout=30  --exclude 'sample' rsync://$rsync_username@$rsync_server/$rsync_path/ $dest_path/
```

So I'm left wondering what I'm overlooking in the boot process that could be hosing name resolution.

In case it's relevant, here's my client's `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return]

networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer to a similar question. The upshot: the name resolution takes too long. As a result, in the script, before the `rsync`, I added a `dig [server.domain.tld]` so the response would be cached. Boom. Issue resolved.